# Is there a clean definition of the residue map in Milnor K-theory?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

If K is a field, v a discrete valuation, and k the residue field, there is a residue map $\partial: K^M_n(K) \to K^M_{n - 1}(k)$. All the definitions I have seen for this map involve two pages of combinatorics of different cases (e.g. the book of Fesenko Vostokov).

Does anyone know of a clean, concise, compact definition of this map, for example via some universal property that it might satisfy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at Lemma 2.1 in [Milnor's original paper](http://0-www.springerlink.com.fama.us.es/content/t025u1152j330325/), $\partial$ is characterized by the following properties: given $\pi, u_i \in K$ with $v(\pi)=1$ and $v(u_i)=0$,

$$\partial(u_1 \cdots  u_n)=0,$$

$$\partial(\pi\cdot u_2 \cdots  u_n)=\bar{u}_2\cdots \bar{u}_n.$$

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF01425486](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01425486) or at [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/142017) ([Zbl 0199.55501](https://zbmath.org/0199.55501)).